# Where can I learn about binary quartic forms?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, reference-request, book-recommendation

While studying a larger problem, I occured upon the question of which integers can be represented by the binary *quartic* form
$$f(x,y)=xy(x^2+y^2)$$
with $x,y\in\mathbb Z$. The standard text *An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers* by Niven, Zuckerman and Montgomery has an excellent chapter on binary quadratic forms, but unfortunately does not go into cubic or quartic forms. A simple Google search on "binary quartic forms" returns multiple papers on the subject, but nothing containing a systematic discussion about it. Several other Number Theory books I've seen do not appear to go into the theory of binary quartic forms either.

> **Question.** Where can I learn about binary *quartic* forms?

Note that although the form $f(x,y)$ mentioned above is one of the reasons I want to learn about this, the purpose of this question is *not* to ask for an answer to the specific question of which integers are represented by $f(x,y)$. A reference/link to any resource (e.g. a textbook) which contains a systematic discussion on the subject from which I can start learning would be most appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Please note that I am mainly looking for a reference for binary **quartic** forms (not quadratic!), over $\mathbb Z$ specifically--although I would be happy to look at references which also discuss forms more generally, and where this is only, say, one of the subsections.

Comment: The rational numbers represented by a binary quadratic form are easy to find from quadratic reciprocity, there is nothing similar for cubic and quartic binary forms. Maybe you are asking for examples of (classes of) quartic forms for which there is a theory telling the rationals and integers represented ?

Comment: @reuns Yes. From the papers I can find online I gather that for particular classes of binary quartic forms, a lot is known about e.g. the (asymptotic) density of integers that can be properly represented. From the [Wiki page][1] there seems to be a lot of work done on the covariants of a binary quartic---I will admit I have no idea what those are, but my impression is that although there might not be an easy and complete description like the case of binary quadratic forms, there are certainly nontrivial results that are known.

  [1]:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_of_a_binary_form

Comment: I know the ring of modular forms which is $\Bbb{C}[E_4,E_6]$ (as a ring it is just the polynomial ring in two variables graded with $\deg(E_4)=2,\deg(E_6)=3$) but it is unclear to me what is the [mentioned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_of_a_binary_form#The_ring_of_invariants) isomorphism to the ring of invariants of quartic binary forms, ie. the ring of polynomials in 5 variables invariant under the $Sym^4$ representation of $SL_2(\Bbb{R})$ which is more a problem of quotient of a variety by a group of automorphisms.